# why i cannot read json data by using keys instead of indexes angular 2?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am currently working in angular 2 and receiving my json data through api. i received that data in following format.

```
{
    "totalItems": 2719,
    "totalPages": 272,
    "results": [
        {
            "SNR_Title": "Acer - 11 11.6\" Refurbished Chromebook - Intel Celeron - 4GB Memory - 16GB eMMC Flash Memory - Gray",
            "SNR_Brand": "Acer",
            "SNR_Description": "Refurbished Acer 11 Chromebook: Slip the Acer Chromebook into your bag and work from anywhere, without recharging, because it has enough battery life to last for a long time on a single charge.  Learn more about refurbished products &#8250;  Learn more about Chromebooks &#8250;",
            "SNR_ImageURL": "https://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5676/5676707_sa.jpg",
            "SNR_ModelNo": "NX.GC1AA.002",
            "SNR_UPC": "841631108389",
            "SNR_SKU": "5676707",
            "SNR_ProductURL": "https://api.bestbuy.com/click/-/5676707/pdp",
            "SNR_Price": "169.99",
            "SNR_Available": "BESTBUY"
        },
        {
            "SNR_Title": "Acer - 11.6\" Chromebook - Intel Celeron - 2GB Memory - 16GB eMMC Flash Memory - White",
            "SNR_Brand": "Acer",
            "SNR_Description": "Acer Chromebook: Browse the Internet and tackle work or school projects with this Acer Chromebook. An 11.6-inch LED backlit display and an Intel HD graphics card provide a rich viewing experience for images and video, and a built-in webcam lets you place video calls with crisp clarity. With its compact size and 9-hour battery life, this Acer Chromebook is ideal for travel.  Learn more about Chromebooks &#8250;",
            "SNR_ImageURL": "https://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/4963/4963801_sa.jpg",
            "SNR_ModelNo": "CB3131C3SZ",
            "SNR_UPC": "888863408634",
            "SNR_SKU": "4963801",
            "SNR_ProductURL": "https://api.bestbuy.com/click/-/4963801/pdp",
            "SNR_Price": "179.0",
            "SNR_Available": "BESTBUY"
        }
]
}
```

and my service or .ts class where i am receiving this look like this.

```
GetAllMobile:Object
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
        this.httpService.getAllMobiles(1).subscribe(
    data => {
      const myArray = [];


      for (let key in data) {
        myArray.push(data[key]);

// console.log(this.GetAllMobile)
      }
        this.GetAllMobile=(myArray) 
    }
  );
```

but i cannot read GetAllMobile.results in my html but i can access it by using index like GetAllMobile[2].
what i have tried so far is following.

```
//Not worked
    <div *ngFor="let item of GetAllMobile">
      <h2>
          Total {{item.totalItems}} {{item.totalPages}} AMAD
      </h2>
          <div *ngFor="let x of item.results">
        <p>
            {{x.SNR_Title}}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>


//this woked but i don't needed this approach
<div *ngFor="let mobile of GetAllMobile[2]">
    <h2>{{ mobile.SNR_Title}}</h2>
   </div>
```

but i can read by using indexes. but for some reasons i want to read data by key. can some body tell me what is right approach to read this data in angular 2.
any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: The response is not an array but an object with an array of `results`. Thus, you should assign `GetAllMobile.results' to `data.results`

Comment: can you please give me some code help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to over complicate things a bit :)

You can just assign the response you are getting as is, no need to try and loop it. So just do:

```
this.httpService.getAllMobiles(1).subscribe(data => {
   this.GetAllMobiles = data;
})
```

Then your template would look like the following. Notice that we are removing the first iteration, since there is nothing to iterate. `GetAllMobile` is an object. The second iteration we keep, as you want to iterate the `results` array that is inside your object.

```html
<h2>Total {{GetAllMobile?.totalItems}} {{GetAllMobile?.totalPages}} AMAD</h2>
<div *ngFor="let x of GetAllMobile?.results">
  <p>{{x.SNR_Title}}</p>
</div>
```

Notice the use of **[safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator)**. It safeguards `null` and `undefined` property paths. Since data is coming asyncronously it is good to use the safe nav operator. In this case this can also be solved by just initializing the variable `GetAllMobile`, but it's useful to know about the safe nav operator in the magical asynchronous world :)

Finally, here's a **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/nZvYiXzDPgVCGYsTrnI2)**

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

try to declare GetAllMobile like this  :

```
GetAllMobile : Array<{totalItems: String, totalPages: string,results: Array<any>}>;
```

hope this will helps you :)